# discord.py отправка сообщения без ввода команды в канале

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

у меня есть код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="")


@Bot.command(pass_context=True)

async def go_say(ctx):
    say_at_me = input("Введите сообщение через консоль: ")
    await ctx.send(say_at_me)



Bot.run('.......')
```

что нужно добавить что бы при запуске бота, можно было писать в дискорд канал без того что бы кто то ввёл команду?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В библиотеке `asyncio` есть [специальный метод](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html?highlight=coroutine_threadsafe#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe) - `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(def(args), loop)`

Он принимает 2 аргумента. Первый - вызываемая функция, второй - поток, в котором ее нужно вызвать. Создадим асинхронную функцию для отправки сообщения. Ее не нужно помечать декоратором `@bot.command()`, так как она не будет являться командой бота.

Функция будет принимать 2 аргумента - ID текстового канала (`int`) и текст для отправки (`str`). После вызова, используя объект бота получаем объект канала из ID и отправляем туда сообщение.

```
async def send_msg(channel, text):
    channel = bot.get_channel(channel)
    await channel.send(text)
```

Как только бот готов к работе (функция-событие бота `on_ready()`), можем принимать в консоли текст и id, а затем передавать их в функцию `send_msg()`, в потоке бота.

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    text = input('Введите сообщение:')
    channel = int(input('Введите ID канала, куда нужно отправить сообщение\n>'))
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(send_msg(channel, text), bot.loop)
```

---

**Полный код:**

```
import discord, asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

async def send_msg(channel, text):
    channel = bot.get_channel(channel)
    await channel.send(text)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    text = input('Введите сообщение:')
    channel = int(input('Введите ID канала, куда нужно отправить сообщение\n>'))
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(send_msg(channel, text), bot.loop)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: он работает, но на один раз, мне так же нужно что бы я после того как ввёл сообщение, повторилось это.

Comment: В чем проблема, добавьте эту конструкцию в цикл. Я вам дал пример кода, вы можете менять его под себя как хотите :)