# Как отправить сообщение вне функции в discord.py?

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Я пытаюсь сделать одну игру, и если игроков в лобби = 10, то начинается игра. В данный момент я сделал проверку через `if`, но при отправке сообщения выдаёт ошибку `outside function`

**Код:**

```
if config.players == 10:
  channel = ds.utils.get(bot.guild.channels, id=950329905512595466)
  await channel.send(f'Старт игры **{config.players}/10**')
```

**Полная ошибка:**

```
    await channel.send(f'Старт игры **{config.players}/10**')
    ^
SyntaxError: 'await' outside function
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/961205

Comment: @denisnumb не особо разобрался, код не рабочий

Comment: Я скинул ссылку не для кода из вопроса, а для того чтобы вы посмотрели на ответ. Там написан пример рабочего кода

Comment: @denisnumb в том то и дело, что он не работает

Comment: просто игнорит...

Comment: Я не понимаю, в чем проблема. Что конкретно непонятно в тексте ошибки про то, что вы пытаетесь использовать `await`  за пределами асинхронной функции? В ответе по ссылке, ясно сказано что избежать этого **никак не получится** и дан пример кода, как можно самостоятельно запустить асинхронную функцию. На крайняк, можно было бы найти другие решения - их очень много, даже я год назад уже писал [ответ на подобный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1270690/373173). Ну и с таким отношением, разумеется, нет никакого желания отвечать на банальный вопрос

Answer (score 1):

```
asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(channel.send('Старт игры'), bot.loop)
```